# Why did Yotsuba say 'are you actually a boy'?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

At around 17:50 in Episode 10 of *The Quintessential Quintuplets*, Uesugi failed to lift a log, then Yotsuba said, 'are you actually a boy, Uesugi-san'.
[image]

But, wait! Let's take a closer look at how Uesugi was trying to lift the log.

[image]

According to [law of the lever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever#Law:%7E:text=the%20cochlea.-,Law%20of%20the%20lever,-%5Bedit%5D), you really shouldn't lift a log from one side. Uesugi did well in all subjects, including physics, so he couldn't be unaware of this. The correct way to lift a log should be like this:

[image]

So, he didn't intend to lift the log by himself from the start. He planned the failure to get Yotsuba to lift the log with him. Then he could probably get the chance to talk with Yotsuba.

How about Yotsuba? She helped the sport club a lot, so it's impossible that she didn't know the common sense how one should lift a log. Yet she still thought Uesugi was too week to lift a log.

Is this a clue that Yotsuba was too simple-minded to get the message from others? Or there is other reason to say, 'are you actually a boy'?

Comment: Why do you keep referring to Fuutarou Uesugi by last name when there are 3 Uesugi's? Do you say the person beside Fuutarou Uesugi is Nakano instead of Yotsuba?

Comment: Anyhoo, that's how 1 person should lift. Yotsuba said when they were already both lifting...Soooo you're talking about a different thing from Yotsuba?

Comment: @BCLC After saying that line, Yotsuba immediately comforted Uesugi, 'b-b-but it's always easier with more help'. This line implies Yotsuba planned that she and Uesugi each lift a log, but anyway, two people lift one log made it easier. Since it was comforting, what she previously said, that is, the line in this question, is more or less a complaint about Uesugi's inability to lift a log by himself.